# How do you solve this differential equation involving equilibria?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This differential equation has 2 equilibrium solutions at $y_1$ and $y_2$ but I can't seem to be able to solve. I made it into a separable equation and started using partial fractions, but I either did not do something correctly or am using the wrong process, as I got stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = -b\left(1-\frac{y}{y_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{y}{y_2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your parentheses and get an equation:
$$y' = -\frac{by^2}{y_1y_2} + b\left(\frac{1}{y_1}+\frac{1}{y_2}\right)y - b$$
which is a Riccati equation. To you know how to solve those?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas of reversing the equation and integrating with respect to $y$ look good to me. For sure, partial fractions should be used for making life much easier.

Doing the same, I arrived to

$$x = c-\frac{\text{y1} \text{y2} (\log (y-\text{y1})-\log (y-\text{y2}))}{b
   (\text{y1}-\text{y2})}$$
from which, now, $y$ can be extracted

$$y=\frac{\text{y2}-\text{y1}}{e^{\frac{b (c-x) (\text{y1}-\text{y2})}{\text{y1}
   \text{y2}}}-1}+\text{y2}$$

$c$ being fixed by a boundary condition.

I hope and wish I did not make any mistake.